# How can I filter a dataset for characters that begin with certain numbers?

Tags: r, filter, tidyverse

I am a beginner with R so I appreciate your patience and help in advance!

Here is the dataset:

```
Zipcode <- as.character(c(28237:28242,18237:18240))
Property_id <- as.character(c(1134730:1134739))
x <- data.frame(Property_id,Zipcode)
```

I would like to filter out all of the zipcodes that began with "18". The final dataset, x, should only contain zipcodes that start with 28.

I think I need to use grepl. I am just not sure how I would code it.

Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
x[substr(Zipcode, 1, 2) != '18', ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Among the many approaches to solve this you can use a negated `grepl` and search for your start-of-the-string (`^`) match like you described

```
x %>% filter(!grepl("^18",Zipcode))
  Property_id Zipcode
1     1134730   28237
2     1134731   28238
3     1134732   28239
4     1134733   28240
5     1134734   28241
6     1134735   28242
```

or, better, use the numbers and do a logical comparison

```
x %>% filter(as.numeric(Zipcode)>19000)
  Property_id Zipcode
1     1134730   28237
2     1134731   28238
3     1134732   28239
4     1134733   28240
5     1134734   28241
6     1134735   28242
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `substr` function from `base` package:

```
# base R:
x[substr(x$Zipcode, 1, 2) != "18", ]

# filter function from dplyr:
x %>% filter(substr(Zipcode, 1, 2) != "18")
```